How to access rules in content compliance in gmail setting , google workspace admin console , "PROGRAMMATICALLY"
I need to programmatically access the content compliance rules set in the Gmail settings from the Google Workspace Admin Console.
Could you please advise if there is an available API or any other programmatic method to achieve this? If so, I would appreciate detailed instructions or documentation that could assist me in implementing this solution.
I need to add / update / modify rules in content compliance , Google workspace admin console , programmatically by using api

Sounds like you can use the Admin SDK API

but there isn't any api for accessing rule in content compliance using admin sdk api

Currently there are no methods or a specific API to achieve the action that you want to perform.
There is a public issue tracker created by the community that you can check in order to wait for this implementation by the Google API team.
Right now all you have to check and see the content compliance rules set in the Gmail settings is on the Admin Console Administration.
This is the public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251045392
